# Intercept and mock WebSockets request/responses with pupeteer

Tags: javascript, websocket, puppeteer

Is there a way to intercept and mock WebSockets requests/responses with puppeteer?

```
  page.on('request', request => {
    console.log('Intercepting Request ', request, { depth: null });
    request.continue();
  });

  page.on('response', response => {
    console.log('Intercepting Response ', response, { depth: null });
    response.abort();
  });
```

does not show the requests/responses made through WebSocket.
This [How to use puppeteer to dump WebSocket data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48375700/how-to-use-puppeteer-to-dump-websocket-data) is answering the question somewhat, but not by using `puppeteer` but by using `ws`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use puppeteer to dump WebSocket data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48375700/how-to-use-puppeteer-to-dump-websocket-data)

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to disable websockets with Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607261/is-it-possible-to-disable-websockets-with-puppeteer)

Answer (score -1):

Did you set the request interception?

```
   await page.setRequestInterception(true)
   page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
     interceptedRequest.continue()
   })
```

Comment: Thats not working for requests made through WebSocket. At least, they do not show up...