# How to connect to a websocket with puppeteer and perform automation on that websocket

Tags: html, web-scraping, websocket, puppeteer, webautomation

On my HTML page, I am trying to perform web-automation on a websocket with puppeteer. I've tried different ways of running this code, but every time I try, I get a variety of different errors. I was wondering if there is a specific code I could use in order to make this work?

My HTML code:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/puppeteer-web">
</script>
<script>
async function run() {
let socket = new WebSocket("wss://javascript.info/article/websocket/demo/hello");

socket.onopen = function(e) {
  console.log("[open] Connection established");
  console.log("Sending to server");
  socket.send("hey");
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log(`[message] Data received from server: ${event.data}`);
};

socket.onerror = function(error) {
  console.log(`[error] ${error.message}`);
};

const browser = await puppeteer.connect({socket});
    const pagesCount = (await browser.pages()).length;
}
run();

</script>
```

Comment: Related: [Intercept and mock WebSockets request/responses with pupeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000827/intercept-and-mock-websockets-request-responses-with-pupeteer). "I get a variety of different errors"--which ones?

Answer (score 1):

Earlier it was possible with [puppeteer-web](https://github.com/entrptaher/puppeteer-web), but not anymore. [Unpackaged versions of puppeteer](https://unpkg.com/browse/puppeteer@5.0.0/) won't work anymore even if you've added them in your HTML source.

You need to use puppeteer on the server (backend) side. So if your app is client side-only so far: you will need a Node.Js server as well to run the scrapers and to make their output data available to your frontend app via an endpoint (most probably you would choose [Express](https://expressjs.com/) for this purpose).